# How to check if a word is in a phrase in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

In my code I compare two arrays. One array is filled with ingredients, and another list is filled with ingredients that the user is allergic to. So let's say the user is allergic to "pork", then he/she would enter "pork". But if the term is "Roasted Pork", it won't compare and so "Roasted Pork" will fly by the radar. This is how I compare the arrays:

```
   NSMutableSet *originalIngredientSet =  [NSMutableSet setWithArray:completeArray];
NSSet *wrongIngredients = [NSSet setWithArray:matchAgainstArray];
[originalIngredientSet intersectSet:wrongIngredients];

NSArray *filteredArray = [originalIngredientSet allObjects];

for (NSString *allergicITem in filteredArray)
{
    if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:allergicITem])

    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else

    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    }
}
```

So my question is: How can I better this block of code so that it will detect words that are inside a phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
 if ([cell.textLabel.text rangeOfString:allergicITem].location != NSNotFound) {
    // red
 } else {
    // black
 }
```

You could also change the attributes of the text range to have a yellow background or something.

Comment: Yeah it seems as this isn't working, for I entered "Chicken" as an allergic ingredient and the app didn't mark "Chicken Fat" red.

Comment: Oh my I am so sorry, I was looping through the WRONG ARRAY. It works fine, a thousand apologies